# Echo ALT attribute of random image

Tags: php, jquery, html, image

I have this little script that displays a random image, which is:

```
<img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/members/00<?php $random = rand(1,7); echo $random; ?>.jpg"alt="[ Random Image ]">
```

This makes the image src `src="example.com/images/001.jpg" alt="[ Random Image ]">` the (1,7) in the script adds the number of the image `001.jpg` to `007.jpg`.

Now what I would like is to change the `"[ Random Image ]"` in to `"$my_alt"` and have it display (echo) the alt attribute of the image in a `<h2 class="myAlt">...</h2>` tag.

I'm not that of a coder, so I don't really know how to do this. I believe I would first need to give `my_alt` a value. So I would go by:

`if {image src="example.com/images/001.jpg" $my_alt = "My first Alt"}
else if {image src="example.com/images/002.jpg" $my_alt = "My second Alt"}`

and then where I want the value of the alt to be placed add the code:
`<h2 class="myAlt"><?php echo $my_alt(); ?></h2>`

Am I doing this correct, is this the right way to go? Like I said I'm not that good at coding, so thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your problem. Try this to see if it works:

```
<!-- I am gonna make a sample template so that you may understand how to use my solution for your specific issue -->
 <div class="imageContainer">
    <img src="something" alt="Image1" />
    <h2 class="myAlt"></h2>
</div>
<div class="imageContainer">
    <img src="something" alt="Image2" />
    <h2 class="myAlt"></h2>
</div>
<div class="imageContainer">
    <img src="something" alt="Image3" />
    <h2 class="myAlt"></h2>
</div>
<div class="imageContainer">
    <img src="something" alt="Image4" />
    <h2 class="myAlt"></h2>
</div>

<script>
$('.imageContainer').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.myAlt').html($(this).find('img').attr('alt'));
});
</script>
```

It will show the respective `alt` below every image.

for particular two images

```
// giving alt dynimically
    $('img').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('src')==='image 001.jpg'){
            $(this).attr('alt','person x');
        }
        else if($(this).attr('src')==='image 002.jpg'){
            $(this).attr('alt','person y');
        }
    });
```

its just an idea, you need to modify it to suit your particular problem. Good luck.
*I hope it helps*

Comment: Thanks! The images show the face of a person. I want to add there names under the images in a `H2` tag (i guessed using the ALT was the best option). I hope that clears things up a bit...

Comment: I updated the answer, i hope you can use it for your condition.Try and tell me if its any issue there.

Comment: This this displays a random image every time you do a refresh?

Comment: Its a sample code having four images and four alt attributes of those images. jquery code under <script> tag takes every image one by one and shows its attr tag under it in h2 tag. I didnt know your question was about showing a random image, i thought it was about showing respective attr attribute in a h2 tag.

Comment: Well no problem... this will point me in the correct way I guess. Do you know how to dynamically give the image 001.jpg the alt `person x` and image 002.jpg the alt `person y`?

Comment: we are talking about only two images: image001.jpg and image002.jpg or you have more than two, you just gave two as an example

Comment: Thanks! Great work. I got it to do exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the help! @abhay Maurya

Comment: No problem.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array with all images and their *alt*s, then choose one of them and display it:

```
<?php
$images = [
  ['file' => '001.jpg', 'alt' => 'My first alt'],
  ['file' => '002.jpg', 'alt' => 'My second alt'],
  ['file' => '003.jpg', 'alt' => 'My third alt'],
  # add more files below
];
$rand = mt_rand(0, count($images) - 1);
?><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/members/<?php echo $images[$rand]['file']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $images[$rand]['alt']; ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but are you sure this code is correct? If I add it in my page it breaks (blank screen... )

Comment: @Steggie: Try it now, I've added missing semicolons to the code. Also there could be a problem if you're running on an old version of PHP (5.3 or older), because these do not support short array syntax.

Comment: Still getting a blank screen. I could place this code everywhere right? Even if I load my jQuery in my footer. That should matter for PHP, right? I checked and my server is running PHP Version 5.3.29. I cant change this ... my hosting provider doesn't do this... Is that a real problem?